# how to take WHERE value from user in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, select, count, where-clause

I'm using NetBeans IDE for connecting with MySQL database and I want to use select query that take  input value from user and put that value in where condition .
and I get this error message 
Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'
It works when I write the value 'A' in the code, but it doesn't work when its an input from the user?

```
String dataSourceName = "testSqlDb";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;
try {
  bloodgroup = jTextField2.getText().trim();
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");
  Statement s = con.createStatement();

  ResultSet rs;
  String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation WHERE blood_group="
      + bloodgroup;

  rs = s.executeQuery(query);

  while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("COUNT(*)=" + rs.getInt("COUNT(*)"));
  }

  s.close();
  con.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "erro",
      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
}
```

Comment: Instead of the driver for the JDBC/ODBC bridge, you might use the official [MySQL driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). **Also beware: your code is susceptible for SQL injection; use a PreparedStatement.** Here not seriously, but you could get the count of users with password "secret" in the name range A-D and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing the ' '

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation WHERE blood_group='"+bloodgroup+"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

IF String values..

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation 
WHERE blood_group='"+bloodgroup+"';
```

If Numeric values..

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation 
WHERE blood_group="+bloodgroup;
```

Also try `System.out.println("bloodgroup=" + bloodgroup);` before executing the query and check if your variable has desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enclose the user input with single quotes.

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation WHERE blood_group='"+bloodgroup+"'";
```

The query string created will then be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation WHERE blood_group = 'A'
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blood_donation WHERE blood_group = A
```

which may be the cause of your problem.